# slds-align_absolute-center ruins my layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I'm trying to use the Lightning Design System whenever I can,
but as soon, as I use `slds-align_absolute-center` all the content gets aligned in a single row, even `<br />` was ignored. Why is that (by design??) and how could I overcome this with simple slds? (not a grid pls!)

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div class="slds-box slds-align_absolute-center">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
        <div>7</div>
        <br />
        <div>8</div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

without `absolute-center`: [image] and with `absolute-center` : [image]

slds-floating didn't help at all :/

Comment: have you tried `slds-text-align_center` to do?

Comment: now I did and it works.. thank you!! I will use this, but Is it the right tool? I mean divs aren't text..

Comment: overall `slds` style is written by some css stuffs.  As per your use case with `slds` styling  you can use  `slds-text-align_center` atlast it uses `text-align:center`   css only . when you using `slds-align_absolute-center`  uses a `display:flex` property with contents to be center thats why you got contents aligned in a single row.

Comment: @vignesh feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can officially accept it :) Maybe you can also add a short description where absolute center should be used.